# A frame. Changing value inside a-text tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm working on my project, which is Web based AR, and i'm using ARjs and Aframe. My question is :

how do i change the value inside `<a-text>` tag using javascript. I've been trying several times using querySelector, ClassName, TagName, but nothing changed. How do i solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, please reproduce your question by posting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **id** property to identify your a-text element:

```
<a-text id="myText" value="Old Text"></a-text>
```

```
document.getElementById('myText').setAttribute('value', 'New Text');
```